# $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a closed set $F$. Modification of $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b].$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous on a closed set $F\subset[a,b]$.

We can assume that $[a,b]\cap F^{c}$ is a disjoint union $\cup^{\infty}_{j=1} (a_j,b_j)$.

$$\phi(x) :=\begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x\in F,\\ f(a_j)+\frac{f(b_j)-f(a_j)}{b_j-a_j}(x-a_j) & \text{if } x\in (a_j,b_j).\end{cases}$$

How do you prove that this $\phi$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?

I can prove this if $a_j,b_j$ are ordered such as $... < a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<...$ but can't in the general case.

**Added:**

Above assumption might not be sufficient...
This question arose in an attempt to prove lusin's theorem.

"If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and continuous almost everywhere, for every $\epsilon \gt 0, $ there exists a continuous function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ such that $m(\{ x\in[a,b]|f(x)\neq \phi(x)\})\lt \epsilon.$"

I understand that there is an open set $O$ such that $m(O) \lt\epsilon$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\cap O^{c}.$

If I can modify $f$ to be continuous on $O$, I complete the proof.

Comment: F is a closed set of [a,b] or respect to R? In this case, is false that [a,b]\cap F^c is \sigma-elemental

Comment: Your formula for $\phi$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a solution, but I give only an idea.

1) First note that if for example $a\not \in F$, one of your interval $(a_j,b_j)$ must be $[a,b_j($. This can easily be solved by adding $a$ to $F$, and defining $f(a)$ as you want. The same for $b$. Then if $a,b \in F$, your representation of $[a,b]\cap F^{c}$ is correct.

2) Now I put $g(x)$ for the function you have constructed on $[a,b]$. Note that your function $f$, continuous on the compact $F$, is uniformly continuous. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\alpha>0$ such that  $x,y\in F$ and $|x-y|<\alpha $ imply $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

3) Let $J=\{j; b_j-a_j\geq \alpha\}$. Then $J$ is a finite set. For $j\in J$, $g$ restricted to $[a_j,b_j]$ is uniformly continuous. Hence there exist $\beta>0$ that we can take $<\alpha$, such that if $x,y\in [a_j,b_j]$ with $j\in J$, such that $|x-y|<\beta$,  we have $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Note also that for any $j$, we have for $x\in |a_j,b_j]$, that  $|g(x)-g(a_j)|\leq |f(b_j)-f(a_j)|$ and $|g(x)-g(b_j)|\leq |f(b_j)-f(a_j)|$.

4) Now take $x,y\in [a,b]$, with $|x-y|<\beta$. Wlog we suppose that $x<y$. There are $4$ different cases: $x,y\in F$, ($x\in F$, $y\not \in F$), ($x\not \in F$, $y\in F$) and $(x\not \in F$, $y\not \in F$). I leave to you the first $3$ cases.

In the $4$-th case,  there exists $j, l$ such that $a_j<x<b_j<a_l<y<b_l$. Then:

a) If $j\in J$ and $l\in J$, as $|b_j-x|$ and $|a_l-y|$ are $<\beta$, we get that $|g(b_j)-g(x)|$ and $|g(a_l)-g(y)|$ are $<\varepsilon$. As $|g(b_j)-g(a_l)|=|f(b_j)-f(a_l)|$ and $|a_l-b_j|\leq |x-y|<\beta<\alpha$, we get $|g(x)-g(y)|<3\varepsilon$.

b) Suppose that $j\not \in J$, and $l\in J$. Then $|g(x)-g(b_j)|\leq |g(a_j)-g(b_j)|=|f(a_j)-f(b_j)|<\varepsilon$. By what we have done in  the case a), we get also $|g(x)-g(y)|<3\varepsilon$

c) Do the same if $j$ and $l$ $\not \in J$.

Hence in this case we have proved that $|x-y|<\beta$ imply $|g(x)-g(y)|<3\varepsilon$. Do the same kind of computations for the first $3$ cases.